# PHPUnit setUp() and $this not working for new objects

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

This works;

```
public function testReturnSuccessXmlIfActionIsCheckOrder()
{   

    $order = new Entity\Order;
    $store = new Entity\Store;

    $order->setStore($store);
```

This results in an error;

```
public $order;

protected function setUp() {
  $order = new Entity\Order;
}

public function testReturnSuccessXmlIfActionIsCheckOrder()
{   
    $store = new Entity\Store;

    $order = $this->order->setStore($store);
```

The error is;

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setStore() on a non-object
```

I'm just trying to tidy up the code and move setting up objects in to the `setUp` method.

Obviously there is a lot more code to this file, but this is essentially the only bit I changed which broke it. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
protected function setUp() {
    $this->order = new Entity\Order;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to prefix the member-variable with `$this` everywhere:

```
public $order;

protected function setUp() {
   $this->order = new Entity\Order;
}

public function testReturnSuccessXmlIfActionIsCheckOrder()
{   
    $store = new Entity\Store;

    $this->order = $this->order->setStore($store); // depends on your usecase
```